# How to check if the number can be represented prime power (nth root is prime or not)

Tags: python, algorithm, primes, number-theory, nth-root

I am trying this problem for a while but getting wrong answer again and again.
number can be very large <=2^2014.
[22086. Prime Power Test](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIMEPOW/)

Explanation about my algorithm:

1. For a Given number I am checking if the number can be represented as form of prime power or not.
2. So the the maximum limit to check for prime power is log n base 2.
3. Finally problem reduced to finding nth root of a number and if it is prime we have our answer else check for all `i` till `log (n base 2)` and `exit`.
4. I have used all sort of optimizations and have tested enormous test-cases and for all my algorithm gives correct answer
5. but Judge says wrong answer.
6. Spoj have another similar problem with small constraints n<=10^18 for which I already got accepted with Python and C++(Best solver in c++)

Here is My python code Please suggest me if I am doing something wrong I am not very proficient in python so my algorithm is a bit lengthy. Thanks in advance.

My Algorithm:

```
import math
import sys
import fractions
import random
import decimal
write = sys.stdout.write
def sieve(n):
    sqrtn = int(n**0.5)
    sieve = [True] * (n+1)
    sieve[0] = False
    sieve[1] = False
    for i in range(2, sqrtn+1):
        if sieve[i]:
            m = n//i - i
            sieve[i*i:n+1:i] = [False] * (m+1)
    return sieve
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
def mr_pass(a, s, d, n):
    a_to_power = pow(a, d, n)
    if a_to_power == 1:
        return True
    for i in range(s-1):
        if a_to_power == n - 1:
            return True
        a_to_power = (a_to_power * a_to_power) % n
    return a_to_power == n - 1
isprime=sieve(1000000)
sprime= [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997]
def smooth_num(n):
    c=0
    for a in sprime:
        if(n%a==0):
            c+=1
        if(c>=2):
            return True;
    return False
def is_prime(n):
    if(n<1000000):
        return isprime[n]
    if any((n % p) == 0 for p in sprime):
        return False
    if n==2:
        return True
    d = n - 1
    s = 0
    while d % 2 == 0:
        d >>= 1
        s += 1
    for repeat in range(10):
        a=random.randint(1,n-1)
        if not mr_pass(a, s, d, n):
            return False
    return True
def iroot(n,k):
    hi = 1
    while pow(hi, k) < n:
        hi *= 2
    lo = hi // 2
    while hi - lo > 1:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        midToK = (mid**k)
        if midToK < n:
            lo = mid
        elif n < midToK:
            hi = mid
        else:
            return mid
    if (hi**k) == n:
        return hi
    else:
        return lo
def isqrt(x):
    n = int(x)
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    a, b = divmod(n.bit_length(), 2)
    x = pow(2,(a+b))
    while True:
        y = (x + n//x)>>1
        if y >= x:
            return x
        x = y
maxx=2**1024;minn=2**64
def nth_rootp(n,k):
    return int(round(math.exp(math.log(n)/k),0))
def main():
    for cs in range(int(input())):
        n=int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
        if(smooth_num(n)):
            write("Invalid order\n")
            continue;
        order = 0;m=0
        power =int(math.log(n,2))
        for i in range(1,power+1):
            if(n<=maxx):
                if i==1:m=n
                elif(i==2):m=isqrt(n)
                elif(i==4):m=isqrt(isqrt(n))
                elif(i==8):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n)))
                elif(i==16):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n))))
                elif(i==32):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n)))))
                elif(i==64):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n))))))
                elif(i==128):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n)))))))
                elif(i==256):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n))))))))
                else:m=int(nth_rootp(n,i))
            else:
                if i==1:m=n
                elif i==2:m=isqrt(n)
                elif(i==4):m=isqrt(isqrt(n))
                elif(i==8):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n)))
                elif(i==16):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n))))
                elif(i==32):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n)))))
                elif(i==64):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n))))))
                elif(i==128):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n)))))))
                elif(i==256):m=isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(isqrt(n))))))))
                else:m=iroot(n,i)
            if m<2:
                order=0
                break
            if(is_prime(m) and n==(m**i)):
                write("%d %d\n"%(m,i))
                order = 1
                break
        if(order==0):
            write("Invalid order\n")
main()
```

Comment: So basically you want to find a number is a power of any prime number?

Comment: @importV Yes Exactly.

Comment: Do you have a list of prime numbers?

Comment: Why do I need List of prime numbers? Also please explain why down voted.

Comment: Because first you have to find prime numbers.

Comment: Downvote is probably because of the code you have provided. Nobody has time to read that much. You should debug it yourself. (P.S. I didn't down vote)

Comment: @importV Then you did not understand the problem correctly. The number can be very large aprox 2^2048 . I think and it can be of any form p^1,P^2 which is very large . SO how can we store those large primes or how can we find those large primes.

Comment: @Lakshman What is the idea behind your `def is_prime(n):`?

Comment: @khajvah That is implementation of Miller Rabin Algorithm .Suppose the given number have 100 digit we can efficiently test if it is prime or not

Comment: one thing that I can think of: perhaps it is because Rabin-Miller test is a randomized algorithm, and you don't repeat the test enough times for certain hard cases?

Comment: @JohnDonn I have tried with 20 and 30 but still WA. I think there is some precision issue with my  " `def nth_rootp(n,k):
    return int(round(math.exp(math.log(n)/k),0))` function.

Comment: it looks like there is indeed a problem with this function: int(round(math.exp(math.log(1940255363782247**37)/37),0)) returns 1940255363782240 on my pc

Comment: (What is the `22086` in the label of the SPOJ link for?)

Comment: @ greybeard 22086 is the problem number on http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIMEPOW/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to read all that code, though I suspect the problem is floating-point inaccuracy. Here is my program to determine if a number *n* is a prime power; it returns the prime *p* and the power *k*:

```
# prime power predicate

from random import randint
from fractions import gcd

def findWitness(n, k=5): # miller-rabin
    s, d = 0, n-1
    while d % 2 == 0:
        s, d = s+1, d/2
    for i in range(k):
        a = randint(2, n-1)
        x = pow(a, d, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n-1: continue
        for r in range(1, s):
            x = (x * x) % n
            if x == 1: return a
            if x == n-1: break
        else: return a
    return 0

# returns p,k such that n=p**k, or 0,0
# assumes n is an integer greater than 1
def primePower(n):
    def checkP(n, p):
        k = 0
        while n > 1 and n % p == 0:
            n, k = n / p, k + 1
        if n == 1: return p, k
        else: return 0, 0
    if n % 2 == 0: return checkP(n, 2)
    q = n
    while True:
        a = findWitness(q)
        if a == 0: return checkP(n, q)
        d = gcd(pow(a,q,n)-a, q)
        if d == 1 or d == q: return 0, 0
        q = d
```

The program uses Fermat's Little Theorem and exploits the witness *a* to the compositeness of *n* that is found by the Miller-Rabin algorithm. It is given as Algorithm 1.7.5 in Henri Cohen's book *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory*. You can see the program in action at http://ideone.com/cNzQYr.

Answer (score 1):

this is not really an answer, but I don't have enough space to write it as a comment.

So, if the problem still not solved, you may try the following function for nth_rootp, though it is a bit ugly (it is just a binary search to find the precise value of the function):

```
def nth_rootp(n,k):
    r = int(round(math.log(n,2)/k))
    left = 2**(r-1)
    right = 2**(r+1)
    if left**k == n:
        return left
    if right**k == n:
        return right
    while left**k < n and right**k > n:
        tmp = (left + right)/2
        if tmp**k == n:
            return tmp
        if tmp == left or tmp == right:
            return tmp
        if tmp**k < n:
            left = tmp
        else:
            if tmp**k > n:
                right = tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

your code look like a little overcomplicated for this task, I will not bother to check it, but the thing you need are the following

1. `is_prime`, naturally
2. a prime generator, optional
3. calculate the nth root of a number in a precise way

for the first one I recommend the deterministic form of the [Miller-Rabin test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants) with a appropriate set of [witness](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongPseudoprime.html) to guaranty a exact result until 1543267864443420616877677640751301 (1.543 x 10<sup>33</sup>) for even bigger numbers you can use the probabilistic one or use a bigger list of witness chosen at your criteria

with all that a template for the solution is as follow

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    ...

def sieve(n):
    "list of all primes p such that p<n"
    ...

def inthroot(x,n):
    "calculate floor(x**(1/n))"
    ...

def is_a_power(n):
    "return (a,b) if n=a**b otherwise throw ValueError"
    for b in sieve( math.log2(n) +1 ):
        a = inthroot(n,b)
        if a**b == n:
            return a,b
    raise ValueError("is not a power")

def smooth_factorization(n):
    "return (p,e) where p is prime and n = p**e if such value exists, otherwise throw ValueError"
    e=1
    p=n
    while True:
        try:
            p,n = is_a_power(p)
            e = e*n
        except ValueError:
            break
    if is_prime(p): 
        return p,e
    raise ValueError

def main():
    for test in range( int(input()) ):
        try:
            p,e = smooth_factorization( int(input()) )
            print(p,e)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid order")

main()
```

And the code above should be self explanatory

**Filling the blacks**

As you are familiar with Miller-Rabin test, I will only mention that if you are interested you can find a implementation of the determinist version [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Python) just update the list of [witness](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongPseudoprime.html) and you are ready to go.

For the `sieve`, just change the one you are using to return a list with primes number like this for instance `[ p for p,is_p in enumerate(sieve) if is_p ]`

With those out of the way, the only thing left is calculate the **nth root** of the number and to do that in a precise way we need to get rip of that pesky floating point arithmetic that only produce headaches, and the answer is implement the [Nth root algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm) using only integer arithmetic, which is pretty similar to the one of `isqrt` that you already use, I guide myself with the one made by [Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254566/wrong-answer-in-spoj-cubert/35276426#35276426) for cube root and generalize it and I get this

```
def inthroot(A, n) :
    "calculate floor( A**(1/n) )"
    #https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm
    #https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#nth_root_algorithm
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254566/wrong-answer-in-spoj-cubert/35276426#35276426
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560902/imprecise-results-of-logarithm-and-power-functions-in-python/39561633#39561633
    if A<0:
        if n%2 == 0:
            raise ValueError
        return - inthroot(-A,n)
    if A==0:
        return 0
    n1 = n-1
    if A.bit_length() < 1024: # float(n) safe from overflow
        xk = int( round( pow(A,1.0/n) ) )
        xk = ( n1*xk + A//pow(xk,n1) )//n # Ensure xk >= floor(nthroot(A)).
    else:
        xk = 1 << -(-A.bit_length()//n) # 1 << sum(divmod(A.bit_length(),n))
                                        # power of 2 closer but greater than the nth root of A
    while True:
        sig = A // pow(xk,n1)
        if xk <= sig:
            return xk
        xk = ( n1*xk + sig )//n
```

and with all the above you can solve the problem without inconvenient

Comment: The number you give "to guaranty a exact result" is a *conjecture*.  The best proven result is Sorenson and Webster (2015) for the first 13 prime bases.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy.ntheory import factorint

q=int(input("Give me the number q=")) 

fact=factorint(q)        #We factor the number q=p_1^{n_1}*p_2^{n_2}*...

p_1=list(fact.keys())    #We create a list from keys to be the the numbers p_1,p_2,...

n_1=list(fact.values())  #We create a list from values to be the the numbers n_1,n_2,...

p=int(p_1[0])            

n=int(n_1[0])            

if q!=p**n:              #Check if the number q=p_{1}[0]**n_{1}[0]=p**n.

    print("The number "+str(q)+" is not a prime power")

else:

    print("The number "+str(q)+" is a prime power")

    print("The prime number p="+str(p))

    print("The natural number n="+str(n))
```